# What should I do to set up the constraint on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a tableview which shows the news. And there's a `UICollectionview` inside each `UITableview` cell. Also there'll be some images inside collection view cell and the number of cells cannot be fixed because news may contain one image, two images or more. 
The 
`UITableview` cell looks like the following structure :

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

name

news info

(`UICollectionview` img1 img2...)

`UIButton` and `UILabel` (such as like, dislike, comment..)

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

and I also set up the constraints. And I have to set up the width attribute for the `UICollectionview`. The main issue is that no matter how many images I may have for the news, the collection view will be always that wide and will block the click event for the tableview cell. So any ideas for that,

thx!

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggest:
set the initial width constraint to 0, then changing it to actual width when bind data to cell.

Comment: Thanks, it really works for me. It's really helpful for a newbie :)